# Graph implementation in C++ using adjacency list

Tags: c++, object-oriented, functional-programming, graph

there is my final code for implementing a Graph in C++ using adjacency list and Object-oriented. I got some help from StackOverflow and it was really helpful, but now I would ask about some advice for improving and a possible way of implementing two functions: `isPath( v, w )` for finding if two nodes are connected and `isConnected(graph)` returning "yes" if the graph is strongly connected otherwise "no".

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Edge {
    int source;
    int target;
};

class Graph
{
private:
    int numOfNodes;
    vector<vector<int>> baseVec;

public:
    Graph(int numOfNodes) : numOfNodes(numOfNodes), baseVec(numOfNodes) {}

    void newEdge(Edge edge) {
        if (edge.source >= numOfNodes || edge.target >= numOfNodes
            || edge.source < 0 || edge.target < 0) {
            cout << "Invalid edge!\n";
            return;
        }
        baseVec[edge.source].emplace_back(edge.target);
        baseVec[edge.target].emplace_back(edge.source);
    }

    void display() {
        for (vector<vector<int>>::size_type i = 0; i < baseVec.size(); i++) {
            cout << "\n Adjacency list of vertex " << i << "\n head: ";
            for (vector<int>::size_type j = 0; j < baseVec[i].size(); j++)
                cout << baseVec[i][j] << " ";
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    int vertex;
    cout << "Enter number of nodes: ";
    cin >> vertex;

    Graph graph(vertex);

    while (true) {
        int source, target;
        cout << "Enter edge ex.1 2 (-1 -1 to exit): \n";
        cin >> source >> target;
        if ((source == -1) && (target == -1))
            break;
        graph.newEdge({ source, target });
    }
    graph.display();
    return 0;
}
```

I really can't find many things to change, so I wrote the `isConnected()` function. Maybe it has some weaknesses or errors. Hope it's useful and I'm still waiting for advice. Thank you!

Code inside the class:

```
    bool isConected(std::vector<int> nodeVec)
        {

            for (st

d::vector<std::vector<int>>::size_type i = 0; i < baseVec.size(); i++)
        {
            if (baseVec[i].empty())
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        for (std::vector<std::vector<int>>::size_type i = 0; i < baseVec.size(); i++)
        {
            for (std::vector<int>::size_type j = 0; j < baseVec[i].size() + 1; j++)
            {
                if (baseVec[i][j] == nodeVec[j + 1])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The line in main:

```
std::vector<int> nodeVec;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertex; i++)
    {
        nodeVec.emplace_back(i);
    }
```

And:

```
if (graph.isConected(nodeVec) == true)
{
    std::cout << "Yes\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "No\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some comments -

- `cout << "Invalid edge"` is not a sane error-relaying mechanism. The C++ way to do things is to throw an exception. The calling code could catch the exception and print an error, or could let the app exit if this is a serious-enough error.
- `void display()` needs to be `void display() const`. It doesn't modify anything.
- Don't iterate through an STL container using an integer index. Iterate using an iterator. If you don't know what I mean, google around or read https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterators-c-stl/

Comment: What do you mean to "Don't iterate through an STL container using an integer index."?  Which lines I have to change?

Comment: `for (vector<vector<int>>::size_type i = 0; i < baseVec.size(); i++) {`